# "Simple" Root-Finding Algorithm

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

What is an exact polynomial root finding algorithm that someone with Algebra 2 experience and who knows all the functions of a TI-nspire could implement? If none, could anyone "dumb-down" a higher level algorithm for me? I've been trying to make my own for quite a while for fun (my definition of fun is... interesting), but have been unsuccessful. The method should preferably be exact rather than approximate, but approximate will work.

Thanks in advance! If anything needs to be clarified, or you find any problems with this question, feel free to let me know! :)
  - JacobTDC

Comment: If it's just polynomials, a combination of bisection and the Newtonian method should be already efficient.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1662609/133152)

Comment: Bisection method seems like the obvious choice here.

Comment: @dbx, sorry, I wasn't clear enough before. I'm looking for an exact method.

Comment: There is no "exact method" for general polynomials of degree at least $5$. I think the exact methods for cubics and quartics wouldn't be easy on a TI. You should have fun coding bisection, or Newton's method.

Comment: Okay, @Ethan Bolker. I'll give it a try.